# How to create a managedObjectContext instance in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I try to use CoreData to save some information.

**This is my ViewController class:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ContactView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        //ERROR
        if let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
            return managedObjectContext
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

**I get the following error:**

> 'Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not
>   NSManagedObjectContext'

I can't understand this error, because  *var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?* should be an optional!? I took exact this example from a Swift reference book...

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSManagedObjectContext` instance in `AppDelegate` is non optional:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.managedObjectContext
}()
```

Don't use *Reference Books*, they might be outdated. Trust the compiler messages.